# Calculated field based on Ranges in a second data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have found similar posts regarding this task, but all of which have a common ID joining the two tables.

I have one data frame which contains sale records (sales_df). For this example I have simplified the data table so that it contains only 5 records. I would like to create a new column in the sales_df that calculates what the fee would be given a sale price amount as defined in the fee table (pricing_fees). Please note that the number of actual pricing fee ranges that I have to account for are around 30, so writing this into a mutate statement is something that I would like to try and avoid.

The two data frames are coded as follows

```
    sales_df <- data.frame(invoice_id = 1:5, 
sale_price = c(100, 275, 350, 500, 675))

    pricing_fees <- data.frame(min_range = c(0, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500), # >=
    max_range = c(50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000), # <
    buyer_fee = c(1, 1, 25, 50, 75, 110, 125))
```

In the end I would like the resulting sales_df to look something like this.

```
  invoice_id sale_price buyer_fee
1          1        100        25
2          2        275        50
3          3        350        75
4          4        500       125
5          5        675       125
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`findInterval`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html) function which is supposed to be efficient in splitting values over ranges (since it uses binary search) :

```
# build consecutive increasing ranges of fees 
# (in order to use findInterval, since it works on ranges defined in a single vector)
pricing_fees <- pricing_fees[order(pricing_fees$min_range),]
consecFees <- data.frame(ranges=c(pricing_fees$min_range[1], pricing_fees$max_range),
                         fees=c(pricing_fees$buyer_fee,NA))
# consecFees now is :
#
#   ranges fees
# 1      0    1  ---> it means for price in [0,50) -> 1
# 2     50    1  ---> it means for price in [50,100) -> 1
# 3    100   25  ---> it means for price in [100,200) -> 25
# 4    200   50  ... and so on
# 5    300   75
# 6    400  110
# 7    500  125
# 8   1000   NA ---> NA because for values >= 1000 we set NA


# add the column to sales_df using findInterval
sales_df$buyer_fee <- consecFees$fees[findInterval(sales_df$sale_price,consecFees$ranges)]
```

Result :

```
> sales_df
  invoice_id sale_price buyer_fee
1          1        100        25
2          2        275        50
3          3        350        75
4          4        500       125
5          5        675       125
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `cut` to "bin" `sales_df$sale_price` values and label bins with corresponding `buyer_fee` values.

```
# Make pricing_fee table with unique buyer_fee
brks <- do.call(rbind, by(pricing_fees, pricing_fees$buyer_fee, FUN = function(x)
    data.frame(min_range = min(x$min_range), max_range = max(x$max_range), buyer_fee = unique(x$buyer_fee))))

sales_df$buyer_fee = as.numeric(as.character(cut(
    sales_df$sale_price,
    breaks = c(0, brks$max_range),
    labels = brks$buyer_fee,
    right = F)))
#  invoice_id sale_price buyer_fee
#1          1        100        25
#2          2        275        50
#3          3        350        75
#4          4        500       125
#5          5        675       125
```